# Regex capture groups in PHP

Tags: php, regex, capture-group

I'm a bit out of my depth here, but I'm trying to let users write links, not entirely unlike how StackOverflow formats links.

Ideally, when a user enters `[text to link here][23]` in a text area, they will end up with `<a href="path/to/img/id/23">text to link here</a>` when that information is written from the database to the page.

My part I'm failing is how to extract `text to link` and `23` from the matched pattern

This is the [pattern I'm using](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5C%5B%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5C-%20%5D%2b%5C%5D%5C%5B%5B0-9%5D%2b%5C%5D&input=Cras%20enim%20mi,%20vulputate%20in%20mollis%20non,%20accumsan%20et%20enim.%20Nulla%20%5Bthe%20link%20goes%20here%5D%5B2%5D%20scelerisque%20gravida%20erat,%20eleifend%20dapibus%20eros%20pulvinar%20at.%20Sed%20a%20magna%20id%20lectus%20tristique%20ultricies.%20Vivamus%20commodo%20lobortis%20dolor,%20ac%20commodo%20velit%20bibendum%20a.%20Sed%20quis%20nibh%20id%20libero%20gravida%20convallis%20a%20sit%20amet%20eros.%20Praesent%20non%20mattis%20eros.%20Mauris%20odio%20sem,%20sodales%20vitae%20adipiscing%20ac,%20volutpat%20sed%20risus.%20Maecenas%20ultricies%20feugiat%20velit,%20eget%20sollicitudin%20eros%20feugiat%20ut.%20Nam%20blandit%20ipsum%20ac%20libero%20aliquet%20sed%20molestie%20neque%20dictum.%20Nullam%20nec%20nunc%20nunc.), but a `preg_replace` using this will only allow me to replace the entire string, not operate on it.  I might be mistaken in my use of preg_replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can operate with `preg_replace_callback`, but even that is unnecessary:

```
preg_replace('/\[(.+?)\]\[(\d+)?\]/', '<a href="path/to/img/id/\2">\1</a>', $st);
```

Comment: This was exactly it, thank you.  I didn't know how to utilize the captured groups in the replacement string.  I also seemed to be over-thinking the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the trick you're looking for: ([[a-zA-Z0-9- ]+])([[0-9]+])
The parenthesis ( and ) are used for grouping...